# How to get the first letter of every words in a string that separated by more than one dot or space

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

This is the problem example :

Input :

**Spy..enigma.....long...address.muscle...anime....time**

Output:

**Selamat**

I can make the '.' disappear but I can't get the first letter of each words. 
Thanks.

this is my code :

```
char dot[] = {'.'}; 

bool isDot(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (c == dot[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (!isDot(str[i])) {
                cout << str[i+1];
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove additional dots so you have **Spy.enigma.long.address.muscle.anime.time**
2. Run for loop to find every character after dot

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str[0];
    // Remove additional dots
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '.' && str[i + 1] == '.') str.erase(i, 1), i--;
    }
    // print every character after dots
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == '.') cout << str[i + 1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: This code will not work if first character is '.', but based on your code I'm assuming it's not.

Or just run a simple `if (s[i] == '.' && s[i + 1] != '.')`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == '.' && str[i + 1] != '.') cout << str[i + 1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the C++11 regular expression library:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::string first_letters(const std::string& input_string) {
    std::string result;
    std::regex word_regex { "[^\\.\\s]*" };
    std::sregex_iterator i { input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), word_regex };
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    while (i != end) {
        result.push_back(i->str().front());
        ++i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, you could learn to use regular expressions. It does require learning how to make regular expression patterns, but there are websites which can help you test your expressions.

Here's an example:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char* acronymMaker(vector<string> wordList) { // reusable function for any string vectors

    if (wordList.size() > 0 ) {  // if there is at least one word in the vector
        char* result = new char[wordList.size() + 1]; // create array big enough for all first characters of each string, and terminating char
        int i = 0; // i is declared outside to be used again
        for (; i < wordList.size(); i++) // for each word
            result[i] = wordList[i][0]; // take first character of each word

        result[i] = '\0'; // add terminating character at end

        return result; // return completed acronym
    }
    return (char*)""; // return empty acronym for 0 words
}

int main(void) { // example using boost::regex and function from above

    string str = "Spy..enigma.....long...address.muscle...anime....time"; //input string
    vector<string> words; // dynamic storage for words
    char* acronym; // acronym to be filled later;

    boost::regex exp{"(\\w+)"}; // regular expression to capture separated words only

    boost::sregex_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), exp); // define iterator parameters
    boost::sregex_iterator end; // empty iterator, same state if no more matches exist or no matches at all

    for (; iter != end; ++iter) { // for each word captured (++ before iter skips first capture, which is the full string being evaluated)
        words.push_back(iter->str()); // push it to the back of the word container
    }

    acronym = acronymMaker(words); // call function

    cout << acronym << endl; // display result on screen

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile this code it will return Selamat as requested. However I am using the boost libraries for my regex, so you'll need to get those too to compile my code. Technically it should also work with the c++11 regex library as the inputs/outputs are the same, but I have had no luck getting it to work, I'll be looking up as to why after this post.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I just have to say...
Take a look at this code:

```
char dot[] = {'.'}; 

bool isDot(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (c == dot[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That is a seriously convoluted way to determine if a character is a dot or not (:

Writing a `for` loop to do a single iteration?
Creating an array to hold a single value?

Howabout this, instead:

```
bool isDot(char c) {
    return c == '.';
}
```

As to your actual question, other people have suggested regex, but [you know what they say about that](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

You can just loop through your input, keeping track of your current state.

How many states can you be in, that you care about?

- The first letter of a word (you want to output these)
- The non-first letter of a word
- A dot (these separate words)

If we call these states `A`, `B`, and `C`, respectively, your example looks like this:

```
Spy..enigma.....long...address.muscle...anime....time
ABBCCABBBBBCCCCCABBBCCCABBBBBBCABBBBBCCCABBBBCCCCABBB
```

This can easily be tracked as you scan your input, left-to-right.
Then you just want to print out the `A` states.

If you want to be slightly clever, you can use only two states:

- The first character after a dot

  - Perhaps with a special exception for the *very first* character in your input, if it's a non-dot.
- Anything else

With these states, you have:

```
Spy..enigma.....long...address.muscle...anime....time
ABBBBABBBBBBBBBBABBBBBBABBBBBBBABBBBBBBBABBBBBBBBABBB
```

Comment: I think I'll try to learn regex too, thanks for the correction on my isDot function, I think I need more practice again. Is regex can be used in competitive programming too?

Comment: @driverA: Programming competitions each have their own sets of rules dictating what is allowed. Whether certain libraries are available (such as regex) would depend on the particular rules. For example, if they let you write in standard Python, then of course regex is available, since it's in the standard library.